# react app not starting on computer with different node and npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

i have 2 computers, while i am sharing one react application. One computer is running the React app just fine; the other, not so much.
Their configurations are slightly different.

Computer 1, macbook (react app is starting):

- node: v13.11.0
- npm 6.13.7

Computer 2, ubuntu 18.04 (react app is not starting):

- node: v10.16.0
- npm: 10.16.0

computer 2 gets the following error when running npm start:

[image]

the error is followed by the following info:

[image]

i have run npm install and npm start again, but to be honest, the differing versions were just my best guess. Would be very grateful to anybody who could help me run the code properly on computer 2!

ps. in the past, i have run react apps totally fine on the linux. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that port might be occupied, try to kill the pid on that port or set start script to run on different port.

To find and kill the PID running on the port-

```
Find the PID:
lsof -i :3000

Kill:
kill -9 <PID>
```

You can change the default port in your package.json file under scripts section-

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3001 && react-scripts start"
```

Comment: would need the log output, but  would assume if might be issue with your npm or react-scripts package. I would try to reinstall both and give it a try.